# Change of adjective in passive voice

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice

I have this sentence:

> They pick the wastages packed every morning.

What would be its passive voice?

> The **packed** wastages are **picked** every morning by them.

Or

> The wastages are **picked packed** every morning by them.

In my opinion it should be the former, in accordance with the rule:

subject (object in active voice) + are + finite verb + object (subject in passive voice)

but I don't know why, I'm still not sure.

Comment: Wastage is wrong here, please see a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never heard the word "wastages" but in the sentence

> They pick up the wastage packed every morning.

the object is the "wastages which are packed"

So

> The *wastages packed every morning* are picked up by them.

is the correct passive version as posted by Mick

If the wastages are packed at another time it could be

> The packed wastages are picked up every morning by them.

Comment: ***They picked up the packed wastage every morning***. There is only picking  up, no picking, this is  not apples and wastage does not take an s.

Comment: Could be - American Pickers pick, they do not pick up. Anyway I changed to pick up

Comment: wastage is misused. I just looked it up. I think they basically pick through stuff people throw out. That is not "wastage". It's junk, and if you see a pile of it, you pick through it. That reality series American Pickers is about picking through stuff, junk, things people throw  out.

Answer (score 3):

I first read the first line as *I **hate** this sentence*...

Since it says,

> *They pick the wastages packed every morning.*

rather than,

> *They pick the packed wastages every morning.*

it should be read as,

> *They pick the wastages [which are] packed every morning.*

Here, *packed* is not an adjective of *wastages*. Thus,

> *The wastages [which are] packed every morning are picked by them.*

or,

> *The wastages packed every morning are picked by them.*